# PHP function's string type declaration accepts integers

Tags: php, type-declaration

I'd have expected the following to generate a type error as `123` is an integer and not a string, so is it okay to provide an integer to a function that expects a string?

```
foo(123);

function foo(string $str) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Also note that strict type declaration doesn't make PHP strictly typed. PHP is still loosely typed. Its just the function/method params and return values that are type checked. See demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0867aa978a85fd0b76079c31215745831e03137c

Comment: Very informative thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because an integer can be converted to string (an array cannot for example).
Yes, unless you declare `declare(strict_types=1)`.

```
foo(123);
function foo(string $str) {
    var_dump($str); // string(3) "123"
}
```

But the following:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

function foo(string $str) { }
foo(123); // FAIL (Uncaught TypeError)
```

Will throw:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: foo(): Argument #1 ($str) must be of type string, int given

Comment: First function call will print `string(3) "123"`!

Comment: Right @Steverst1, was a typo! Corrected, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php) is pretty specific about this behavior, and speaks directly to the example you posed:

> By default, PHP will coerce values of the wrong type into the expected scalar type declaration if possible. For example, a function that is given an int for a parameter that expects a string will get a variable of type string.

Whether this is "OK" or not (as you asked) is highly implementation-dependent.

Comment: but if we were in strict mode `declare(strict_types=1);` will throw an error !